# How to email patches formatted with git format-patch?

Tags: git, email, patch, format-patch

I've got a series of patches I want to send to an open source project but I'm not able to figure out how to properly format an email. I tried running a git format-patch command then attached them all into an email from Thunderbird but they all got rejected because each patch is supposed to be a separate email in itself. I want to avoid the git email commands because I have code in the same tree that is private and some that I need to send, which means I need to be able to manually review each email before it is sent.

I want to keep using Thunderbird, but there seem to be problems with it since it wraps lines and makes patches unusable. I also tried setting up fetchmail and mutt, but after literally 10 hours of reading and trying I gave up. Is there a non-fetchmail and non-thunderbird solution for sending git patches?

Comment: See [Send git Patches Using GUI Email Clients](https://www.topbug.net/blog/2016/12/13/send-git-patches-using-gui-email-clients/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`git help format-patch` has a section "MUA-SPECIFIC HINTS" that mentions three approaches to specifically make Thunderbird usable with git:

- the Toggle Word Wrap add-on
- configure Thunderbird to not mangle patches
- or using an external editor

Comment: hmm, I don't have that section on my computer. Will check google...indeed google has it.

Comment: the 2nd alternative `configure Thunderbird to not mangle patches` doesn't work anymore, maybe time to switch to Geary?

Answer (score 13):

Let me generously paste the [documentation of the Linux project](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.15-rc2/process/email-clients.html).  I'm not limiting it to Thunderbird because the title of you question indicates general interest, rather than Thunderbird only.  Also, check the source for updates, maybe via [this link](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/process/email-clients.html), as it's likely that updates won't propagate to this answer.

## Email clients info for Linux

### Git

These days most developers use `git send-email` instead of regular
email clients.  The man page for this is quite good.  On the receiving
end, maintainers use `git am` to apply the patches.

If you are new to git then send your first patch to yourself.  Save it
as raw text including all the headers.  Run `git am raw_email.txt` and
then review the changelog with `git log`.  When that works then send
the patch to the appropriate mailing list(s).

### General Preferences

Patches for the Linux kernel are submitted via email, preferably as
inline text in the body of the email.  Some maintainers accept
attachments, but then the attachments should have content-type
"text/plain".  However, attachments are generally frowned upon because
it makes quoting portions of the patch more difficult in the patch
review process.

Email clients that are used for Linux kernel patches should send the
patch text untouched.  For example, they should not modify or delete tabs
or spaces, even at the beginning or end of lines.

Don't send patches with "format=flowed".  This can cause unexpected
and unwanted line breaks.

Don't let your email client do automatic word wrapping for you.
This can also corrupt your patch.

Email clients should not modify the character set encoding of the text.
Emailed patches should be in ASCII or UTF-8 encoding only.
If you configure your email client to send emails with UTF-8 encoding,
you avoid some possible charset problems.

Email clients should generate and maintain References: or In-Reply-To:
headers so that mail threading is not broken.

Copy-and-paste (or cut-and-paste) usually does not work for patches
because tabs are converted to spaces.  Using xclipboard, xclip, and/or
xcutsel may work, but it's best to test this for yourself or just avoid
copy-and-paste.

Don't use PGP/GPG signatures in mail that contains patches.
This breaks many scripts that read and apply the patches.
(This should be fixable.)

It's a good idea to send a patch to yourself, save the received message,
and successfully apply it with 'patch' before sending patches to Linux
mailing lists.

### Some email client (MUA) hints

Here are some specific MUA configuration hints for editing and sending
patches for the Linux kernel.  These are not meant to be complete
software package configuration summaries.

Legend:
TUI = text-based user interface
GUI = graphical user interface

### Alpine (TUI)

Config options:
In the "Sending Preferences" section:

- "Do Not Send Flowed Text" must be enabled
- "Strip Whitespace Before Sending" must be disabled

When composing the message, the cursor should be placed where the patch
should appear, and then pressing CTRL-R let you specify the patch file
to insert into the message.

### Claws Mail (GUI)

Works. Some people use this successfully for patches.

To insert a patch use Message->Insert File (CTRL+i) or an external editor.

If the inserted patch has to be edited in the Claws composition window
"Auto wrapping" in Configuration->Preferences->Compose->Wrapping should be
disabled.

### Evolution (GUI)

Some people use this successfully for patches.

When composing mail select: Preformat
  from Format->Paragraph Style->Preformatted (Ctrl-7)
  or the toolbar

Then use:
  Insert->Text File... (Alt-n x)
to insert the patch.

You can also "diff -Nru old.c new.c | xclip", select Preformat, then
paste with the middle button.

### Kmail (GUI)

Some people use Kmail successfully for patches.

The default setting of not composing in HTML is appropriate; do not
enable it.

When composing an email, under options, uncheck "word wrap". The only
disadvantage is any text you type in the email will not be word-wrapped
so you will have to manually word wrap text before the patch. The easiest
way around this is to compose your email with word wrap enabled, then save
it as a draft. Once you pull it up again from your drafts it is now hard
word-wrapped and you can uncheck "word wrap" without losing the existing
wrapping.

At the bottom of your email, put the commonly-used patch delimiter before
inserting your patch:  three hyphens (---).

Then from the "Message" menu item, select insert file and choose your patch.
As an added bonus you can customise the message creation toolbar menu
and put the "insert file" icon there.

Make the composer window wide enough so that no lines wrap. As of
KMail 1.13.5 (KDE 4.5.4), KMail will apply word wrapping when sending
the email if the lines wrap in the composer window. Having word wrapping
disabled in the Options menu isn't enough. Thus, if your patch has very
long lines, you must make the composer window very wide before sending
the email. See: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=174034

You can safely GPG sign attachments, but inlined text is preferred for
patches so do not GPG sign them.  Signing patches that have been inserted
as inlined text will make them tricky to extract from their 7-bit encoding.

If you absolutely must send patches as attachments instead of inlining
them as text, right click on the attachment and select properties, and
highlight "Suggest automatic display" to make the attachment inlined to
make it more viewable.

When saving patches that are sent as inlined text, select the email that
contains the patch from the message list pane, right click and select
"save as".  You can use the whole email unmodified as a patch if it was
properly composed.  There is no option currently to save the email when you
are actually viewing it in its own window -- there has been a request filed
at kmail's bugzilla and hopefully this will be addressed.  Emails are saved
as read-write for user only so you will have to chmod them to make them
group and world readable if you copy them elsewhere.

### Lotus Notes (GUI)

Run away from it.

### Mutt (TUI)

Plenty of Linux developers use mutt, so it must work pretty well.

Mutt doesn't come with an editor, so whatever editor you use should be
used in a way that there are no automatic linebreaks.  Most editors have
an "insert file" option that inserts the contents of a file unaltered.

To use 'vim' with mutt:
  set editor="vi"

If using xclip, type the command
  :set paste
  before middle button or shift-insert or use
  :r filename

if you want to include the patch inline.
(a)ttach works fine without "set paste".

You can also generate patches with 'git format-patch' and then use Mutt
to send them:
    $ mutt -H 0001-some-bug-fix.patch

Config options:
It should work with default settings.
However, it's a good idea to set the "send_charset" to:
  set send_charset="us-ascii:utf-8"

Mutt is highly customizable. Here is a minimum configuration to start
using Mutt to send patches through Gmail:

```
# .muttrc
# ================  IMAP ====================
set imap_user = 'yourusername@gmail.com'
set imap_pass = 'yourpassword'
set spoolfile = imaps://imap.gmail.com/INBOX
set folder = imaps://imap.gmail.com/
set record="imaps://imap.gmail.com/[Gmail]/Sent Mail"
set postponed="imaps://imap.gmail.com/[Gmail]/Drafts"
set mbox="imaps://imap.gmail.com/[Gmail]/All Mail"

# ================  SMTP  ====================
set smtp_url = "smtp://username@smtp.gmail.com:587/"
set smtp_pass = $imap_pass
set ssl_force_tls = yes # Require encrypted connection

# ================  Composition  ====================
set editor = `echo \$EDITOR`
set edit_headers = yes  # See the headers when editing
set charset = UTF-8     # value of $LANG; also fallback for send_charset
# Sender, email address, and sign-off line must match
unset use_domain        # because joe@localhost is just embarrassing
set realname = "YOUR NAME"
set from = "username@gmail.com"
set use_from = yes
```

The Mutt docs have lots more information:
    http://dev.mutt.org/trac/wiki/UseCases/Gmail
    http://dev.mutt.org/doc/manual.html

### Pine (TUI)

Pine has had some whitespace truncation issues in the past, but these
should all be fixed now.

Use alpine (pine's successor) if you can.

Config options:
- quell-flowed-text is needed for recent versions
- the "no-strip-whitespace-before-send" option is needed

### Sylpheed (GUI)

- Works well for inlining text (or using attachments).
- Allows use of an external editor.
- Is slow on large folders.
- Won't do TLS SMTP auth over a non-SSL connection.
- Has a helpful ruler bar in the compose window.
- Adding addresses to address book doesn't understand the display name
  properly.

### Thunderbird (GUI)

Thunderbird is an Outlook clone that likes to mangle text, but there are ways
to coerce it into behaving.

- Allow use of an external editor:
  The easiest thing to do with Thunderbird and patches is to use an
  "external editor" extension and then just use your favorite $EDITOR
  for reading/merging patches into the body text.  To do this, download
  and install the extension, then add a button for it using
  View->Toolbars->Customize... and finally just click on it when in the
  Compose dialog.

  Please note that "external editor" requires that your editor must not
  fork, or in other words, the editor must not return before closing.
  You may have to pass additional flags or change the settings of your
  editor. Most notably if you are using gvim then you must pass the -f
  option to gvim by putting "/usr/bin/gvim -f" (if the binary is in
  /usr/bin) to the text editor field in "external editor" settings. If you
  are using some other editor then please read its manual to find out how
  to do this.

To beat some sense out of the internal editor, do this:

- Edit your Thunderbird config settings so that it won't use format=flowed.
  Go to "edit->preferences->advanced->config editor" to bring up the
  thunderbird's registry editor.
- Set "mailnews.send_plaintext_flowed" to "false"
- Set "mailnews.wraplength" from "72" to "0"
- "View" > "Message Body As" > "Plain Text"
- "View" > "Character Encoding" > "Unicode (UTF-8)"

### TkRat (GUI)

Works.  Use "Insert file..." or external editor.

### Gmail (Web GUI)

Does not work for sending patches.

Gmail web client converts tabs to spaces automatically.

At the same time it wraps lines every 78 chars with CRLF style line breaks
although tab2space problem can be solved with external editor.

Another problem is that Gmail will base64-encode any message that has a
non-ASCII character. That includes things like European names.

Comment: The link to the Linux project documentation is now dead. The latest URL is: 

https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/process/email-clients.html

Which at the time of writing is currently:

https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.15-rc2/process/email-clients.html

Comment: Thanks! I've updated the answer to use the new URLs.

Comment: Thunderbird's `"View" > "Character Encoding" > "Unicode (UTF-8)"` setting no longer exists, any clue what needs to be done nowadays?

Answer (score 8):

You can usually just drag and drop the files generated by git format-patch into your Drafts folder.  I know this at least works with the Evolution mail client.

Comment: The problem I see with Evolution is that it wraps words and thus messes up the patch :-/ At least it does for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using git format-patch, make sure to use it with Git 2.27 (Q2 2020): The output from "`git format-patch`" uses [RFC 2047 encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047) for **non-ASCII letters on `From:` and `Subject:` headers**, so that it can directly be fed to e-mail programs.

A new option has been added to produce these headers in raw.

That way, you don't have to deal with encoding if your email client understands just ASCII.

See [commit 19d097e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/19d097e3d73b4d3635bbe0e8735b2f059d59f29a) (08 Apr 2020) by [Emma Brooks (``)](https://github.com/).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit f4216e5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f4216e5968778a8710e5fc0f4dc7ecdcc53b6448), 22 Apr 2020)</sup>

> ### [`format-patch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/19d097e3d73b4d3635bbe0e8735b2f059d59f29a): teach `--no-encode-email-headers`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Emma Brooks</sup>
>
> When commit subjects or authors have non-ASCII characters, [`git format-patch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch) [Q-encodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Encoded-Word) them so they can be safely sent over email.
>
> However, if the patch transfer method is something other than email (web review tools, sneakernet), this only serves to make the patch metadata harder to read without first applying it (unless you can decode RFC 2047 in your head).
>
> [`git am`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-am) as well as some email software supports non-Q-encoded mail as described in [RFC 6531](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6531).
>
> Add `--[no-]encode-email-headers` and `format.encodeEmailHeaders` to let the user control this behavior.

---

And before Git 2.43 (Q4 2023), "[`git [`format-patch `--rfc` --subject-prefix=`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/09684a12b05b6c01c638cb14e3d765a93d154e32/Documentation/git-format-patch.txt#L241)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch#Documentation/git-format-patch.txt---rfc))</sup><foo>`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/09684a12b05b6c01c638cb14e3d765a93d154e32/Documentation/git-format-patch.txt#L241)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch#Documentation/git-format-patch.txt---rfc))</sup> used to ignore the `--subject-prefix` option and used `[RFC PATCH]`"; now we will add "`RFC`" prefix to whatever subject prefix is specified.

This is a backward compatible change that may deserve a note.

See [commit e0d7db7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e0d7db7423a91673c001aaa5e580c815ce2f7f92) (30 Aug 2023) by [Drew DeVault (`ddevault`)](https://github.com/ddevault).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 09684a1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/09684a12b05b6c01c638cb14e3d765a93d154e32), 07 Sep 2023)</sup>

> ### [`format-patch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e0d7db7423a91673c001aaa5e580c815ce2f7f92): `--rfc` honors what `--subject-prefix` sets
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Drew DeVault</sup>

> Rather than replacing the configured subject prefix (either through the [`git config`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e0d7db7423a91673c001aaa5e580c815ce2f7f92/Documentation/git-config.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config))</sup> or command line) entirely with "`RFC PATCH`", this change prepends RFC to whatever subject prefix was already in use.
>
> This is useful, for example, when a user is working on a repository that has a subject prefix considered to disambiguate patches:
>
> ```
> git config format.subjectPrefix 'PATCH my-project'
> ```
>
> Prior to this change, formatting patches with `--rfc` would lose the 'my-project' information.
>
> The data flow for the subject-prefix was that rev.subject_prefix were to be kept the authoritative version of the subject prefix even while parsing command line options, and sprefix variable was used as a temporary area to futz with it.
> Now, the parsing code has been refactored to build the subject prefix into the sprefix variable and assigns its value at the end to `rev.subject_prefix`, which makes the flow easier to grasp.

`git format-patch` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e0d7db7423a91673c001aaa5e580c815ce2f7f92/Documentation/git-format-patch.txt#L220-L228):

> line, instead use '[]'. This can be used
> to name a patch series, and can be combined with the
> `--numbered` option.
>
> The configuration variable `format.subjectPrefix` may also be used
> to configure a subject prefix to apply to a given repository for
> all patches. This is often useful on mailing lists which receive
> patches for several repositories and can be used to disambiguate
> the patches (with a value of e.g. "`PATCH my-project`").

`git format-patch` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e0d7db7423a91673c001aaa5e580c815ce2f7f92/Documentation/git-format-patch.txt#L238-L240):

> Prepends "`RFC`" to the subject prefix (producing "`RFC PATCH`" by
> default). RFC means "`Request For Comments`"; use this when sending
> an experimental patch for discussion rather than application.

---

"[`git format-patch --encode-email-headers`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/429748517298b37d686d592a18d17a14e4280b92/Documentation/git-format-patch.txt#L311)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch#Documentation/git-format-patch.txt---encode-email-headers))</sup> ignored the option when preparing the cover letter, which has been corrected with Git 2.44 (Q1 2024).

See [commit 219d54a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/219d54ae8c96bcb84d0216797af7572fff7199b8) (09 Nov 2023) by [Simon Ser (`emersion`)](https://github.com/emersion).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 4297485](https://github.com/git/git/commit/429748517298b37d686d592a18d17a14e4280b92), 09 Dec 2023)</sup>

> ### [`format-patch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/219d54ae8c96bcb84d0216797af7572fff7199b8): fix ignored `encode_email_headers` for cover letter
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Simon Ser</sup>

> When writing the cover letter, the `encode_email_headers` option was ignored.
> That is, UTF-8 subject lines and email addresses were written out as-is, without any Q-encoding, even if `--encode-email-headers` was passed on the command line.
>
> This is due to `encode_email_headers` not being copied over from struct `rev_info` to struct `pretty_print_context`.
> Fix that and add a test.